# Couldn't iterate over a dictionary context variable in template, despite having all in place, as far as I know?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate over the keys of a dictionary passed as context variable in template. But it's just not happening.
And when I put {{ key }} in template I get the value corresponding to that key but just couldn't iterate over.

**logic.py**

```
global table
table = {}

for i in range(9):
   for j in range(9):
       key = 'i'
       key = key + str(i) + str(j)
       table[key] = 1
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .formss import SudokuForm, RealSudoku
from .logic import table
# Create your views here.

def sudokuf(request):
    title = "Sudoku Puzzle"

    if request.method == 'POST' :
       print(request.POST)
return render (request,"sudoku.html",table)
```

**sudoku.html**

```
<form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}

    {% for key,value in table.items %}
        {{ key }}:{{ values }}
    {% endfor %}

    {{ i04 }} # If I do this I get the value table['i04'] but not in the above  for loop

    <input type="submit" align="centre" value="Solve">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to `render` is a "context", a dictionary whose keys will be available to your HTML as names. You're passing your `table` object as the context, so its keys (like `i04`) are available as variables... but there is no key named `table` in your table, so the name `table` isn't available to your HTML.

Change this line in view.py:

```
return render (request,"sudoku.html",table)
```

to:

```
return render(request, "sudoku.html", {"table": table})
```

And you'll have the name `table` available in your HTML. (But **not** the name `i04`).

You could also do something like:

```
import logic
render(request, "sudoku.html", logic)
```

And that would make all the names defined in your `logic` module available to your HTML.

If there's anything that's not clear about this answer, leave a comment and let me know, and I'll try to explain further.

Comment: yes, return render(request, "sudoku.html", {"table": table})is the correct format.

Comment: Thanks a lot rmunn !!!! Just started learning Django, very grateful for your answer. It just started working, going to look deeper in what all you suggested. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that you have `{{ values }}` where you should have `{{ value }}`.

So instead of

```
{% for key,value in table.items %}
    {{ key }}:{{ values }}
{% endfor %}
```

try...

```
{% for key,value in table.items %}
    {{ key }}:{{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In addition to the answer that I posted, part of this answer is also correct: your `{{ key }}:{{ values }}` line should be `{{ key }}:{{ value }}`. However, the part saying that you can't do `for a,b in x` is wrong: [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for) specifically mentions that you can do that.

Comment: @rmunn: Oooh, thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit that out.

Comment: Now that the answer is entirely correct, I'm happy to give it a +1.

Comment: @rmunn: I +1'd yours too. :)

Comment: Actually I was't getting anything, niether the keys only, if {{values}} would have been a problem I should have got atleast {{key}}. But nothing earlier. And thanks for pointing that out too !!